# How do I write the SQL to retrieve records for a single date from Access database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I can retrieve all of the records between two dates from an Access database using this statement;

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ID_1 as SampleID, ID_2 as TestID FROM Results WHERE TestDate Between #" +
                        startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# AND #" + endDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#"
```

but when I try to get a single date I get no records.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ID_1 as SampleID, ID_2 as TestID FROM Results WHERE TestDate = #" +
                        startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#";
```

The first attempt did not include the time which is part of the Date field in the data base. So I tried to format the date to include time in HH:mm:ss but that also returned 0 records.

What is wrong with the sql statement? This is an Access database.

Comment: Use parameterised queries. That way you don't need to worry about formatting dates correctly.

Comment: You could query where Year = year of parameter and Month = the month and Day = the day. Or you can do another between from midnight to midnight

Comment: I was able to run a similar query against one of our Access databases without issue.  Are you sure there is data to satisfy the single date you are providing?  What happens if you provide the same date for the between parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming OleDB:

```
var SQL = @"
SELECT DISTINCT ID_1 as SampleID, ID_2 as TestID 
FROM Results 
WHERE TestDate >= ? AND TestDate < ?";

var cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL);
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = startDate.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OldDbType.Date).Value = startDate.Date.AddDays(1);
```

If you're using ODBC it will look similar, with just slightly different naming for the command and enum.

Some things of note:

- Never *never* **NEVER** use string concatenation to put data in queries! I can't emphasize enough how important this is! Not only is it faster and helps you avoid basic data issues like someone who's last name is `O'Brien` or (ahem) correctly formatting your date literals, but failing to do this is the easiest way I know to find out a year from now that you were hacked six months ago.
- If you ever find yourself trying to format a date string in code for use in an SQL query, you're doing something horribly wrong. Use the C# `datetime` type and let ADO.Net handle this for you via parameterized query.
- Prefer separate conditions over BETWEEN for date ranges covering full days, with the inclusive `>=` on the lower bound and the exclusive `<` for the *day after* the upper bound. This can sometimes be faster, bust mostly it's just *more correct* around the boundaries, where BETWEEN can sometimes give the wrong results if you are not careful on how you structure your data and write your boundaries.

Comment: In my experience > lower bound as date is perfectly reasonable. Do you really get dates added at exactly midnight? I come from a really old mindset, that bothered about such things as clock cycles. >= Is more expensive than > so only use it when you really have to.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I've worked on several systems where you have multiple sources inserting the data, some of which would leave off the time portion (so we DO have dates right exactly for midnight). Since `BETWEEN` is inclusive at both ends of the range, I tend to be worried about those dates at end of the range falling on midnight and end up getting counted for both days.

Comment: This is NOT production code. It will never see a computer except mine. I was just trying to fetch certain records and a single date would not work. Getting past your fear of an injection attack, it looks like the answer is "it can't be done." I will have to get records greater than or equal to the given date and less than one day past the given date, in other words another BETWEEN. I don't care about all the other things you mentioned, just the single date question. Joel, thank you for your comment. No record will ever be recorded after regular hours, so, in this case, between is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the time part:

```cs
"SELECT DISTINCT ID_1 as SampleID, ID_2 as TestID FROM Results " +
"WHERE Fix(TestDate) = #" + startDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```

or use an interval:

```cs
"SELECT DISTINCT ID_1 as SampleID, ID_2 as TestID FROM Results " +
"WHERE TestDate >= #" + startDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# and " +
"TestDate < #" + startDate.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```